# Express/Node.js Page Refresh Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, server

I'm a beginner in anything to do with web development with servers (only took one course in uni). I have a weird issue relating to a GET request where if I refresh too many times, it just stops being sent. Here is the output from npm start when it does work:

```
GET / 304 0.350 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/styles.css 404 28.359 ms - 1132
GET /javascripts/scripts.js 304 0.244 ms - -
GET /favicon.ico 404 11.692 ms - 1132
GET /skaterSummary.json 304 51.770 ms - -
```

After spamming refresh a lot, the output becomes like this:

```
GET /skaterSummary.json - - ms - -
GET / 304 0.676 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/styles.css 404 28.628 ms - 1132
GET /javascripts/scripts.js 304 0.599 ms - -
GET /favicon.ico 404 20.098 ms - 1132
```

**Code: routes/index.js**

```
// Database Testing
router.get('/skaterSummary.json', function(req, res, next) {
    req.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var query = "SELECT * from Summary;";
        connection.query(query, function(err, results) {
            res.json(results); // send response
        });
    });
});
```

**Code: scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open('GET', 'skaterSummary.json', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks for any pointers :)

Comment: What stops being sent? `skaterSummary.json`? Did you check the browser console?

Comment: Yes, skaterSummary.json stops being sent. Only when its sent I get the json in the browser console.

Comment: I'd add `if (err) throw err;` to your `connection.query` callback.

Comment: I thought this fixed it! Was working for a while but then the same thing happened again :(

Comment: It's not supposed to fix anything, it's supposed to display an error if an error occurs, as opposed to doing nothing.

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is most likely an error coming back from either DB request, throwing the error (particularly in an asynchronous callback) won't do anything, it won't be propagated therefore can't be handled, meaning any pending requests will simply hang until they eventually timeout.

The best way of handling this is to call `next` and pass the error to Express, you can then add your own custom error handler or leverage the default one from Express

```
router.get('/skaterSummary.json', function(req, res, next) {
  req.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err); // log the DB error internally
      return next(new Error('Server Error')); // return a client error
    }

    var query = "SELECT * from Summary;";
    connection.query(query, function(err, results) {
      if (err) { 
        console.error(err);
        return next(new Error('Server Error')); 
      }

      res.json(results); // send response
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too clear on what to do from this. Should the default Express error handler be able to handle this error? Because the requests eventually still stall.  I'm not too sure how to write a custom one. Also, there don't seem to be any console messages about the error.

Comment: @davidhin the default Express error handler will end the request, but also just realised that this is an AJAX response and as such you'll want to to be returning a JSON response so you would want a custom handler in this case. However, if you are saying there are zero errors then clearly that isn't the problem, how many refreshes are we talking about here? Could you be exhausting your DB connection pool? Even then I'd still expect an error...

Comment: Also FWIW, you are aware of [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)? Would really simplify your client-side code.